# firebase firestore is working locally but not when deployed in angular. Error: Service firestore is not available

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angularfire

I have added @angular/fire to my project to use firestore and it worked fine locally and it was writing to the firestore. However, when I deployed it (to my firebase hosting). It stopped working.
**Note that**: I didn't get any errors when performing the build.

This is the error i get on the deployed app

> core.mjs:6412 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Service firestore is not available
> Error: Service firestore is not available

This is the version of @angular/fire that I am using

```
"@angular/fire": "^7.6.1",
```

My environment files look as follows

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    firebaseConfig: {
        apiKey: '***'
        authDomain: '***'
        projectId:  '***'
        storageBucket:'***',
        messagingSenderId:  '***',
        appId:  '***',
        measurementId:  '***'
    },
};
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    ... (same as env.ts)
};
```

Here is how I am innitialzing firebase

**app.module.ts**

```
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from "@angular/fire/app";
import { provideFirestore, getFirestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore"

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),
        provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is how I am injecting firestore to my service

```
import { Firestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root",
})
export class FirebaseService {
    constructor(private firestore: Firestore) {...}
```

Comment: can you show the environment import

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen 


This is in the app.module 


import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";
and in prod I am doing 
 "fileReplacements": [
        {
         "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
         "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }

Comment: just wanted to be sure that it wasn't targeting prod from some reason and then not have any due to replacement

Comment: I suspect you are missing service worker js.

Comment: @BibekKhadka how to add it?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the package-lock.json file and the node_modules directory. Then, I installed the following versions:

```
...
"@angular/fire": "7.6.1",
"firebase": "9.12.1",
"rxfire": "6.0.3"
...
```

It's now working for Angular 15.0.4.
Refer: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3422#issuecomment-1732511999